# Flask behind gunicorn not visible

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

I have a flask app

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run( 
    host="0.0.0.0",
    port=8088,
    debug = False,
    use_reloader=False,
    threaded=True
)
```

which i want to run behind Gunicorn. Everything works fine I can reach it externally and locally when just running it stand alone.

Running it with gunicorn:

```
gunicorn service:app -b :8088 --workers 10 --preload
```

I can still reach it locally but externally i can no longer reach it.

The output looks fine:

```
[2017-09-01 11:24:33 +0000] [8813] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.7.1
[2017-09-01 11:24:33 +0000] [8813] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8088 (8813)
[2017-09-01 11:24:33 +0000] [8813] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2017-09-01 11:24:33 +0000] [8823] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8823
```

I can't figure out why I no longer can reach it after its behind gunicorn. Any ideas?

```
socket.error: [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

Comment: Try to put the ``app.run`` call into a ``if __name__ == "__main__":`` block to avoid guicorn and flask both opening the same port when the script is run with gunicorn.

Comment: Yes, sorry for omitting that. I do have it like that.